# New FB notifications API 1:1 to send to 19k users

Tags: facebook, notifications

I have a problem in sending via CURL notifications to 19k users.

The new FB app notifications API is goldmine, so i've implemented a system into my app that notifies a player when his friend has a higher score than him.
The problem is that the app has to send 19k notifications through curl and it takes ~950 hours. 
Is there a faster sollution to send these nitifications ? I mean i have seen most of the big players (like zynga) are succesfully using the app notifications and i don't thing they have less notifications to send than me :)

here's my code

```
    function _getAppToken(){
            $APPLICATION_ID = "xxxxxxx";
            $APPLICATION_SECRET = "xxxxxxxx";

            $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?" .
                "client_id=" . $APPLICATION_ID .
                "&client_secret=" . $APPLICATION_SECRET .
                "&grant_type=client_credentials";
            //$app_token = file_get_contents($token_url);
            $accessToken = explode('=', file_get_contents($token_url));
            return $accessToken[1];
        }
```

```
    function _curlDoNotifications($fb_id, $tokennn, $mesaj, $hrf = '')
        {
            $attachment = array(
                'access_token' => $tokennn,
                'href' => $hrf,
                'template' => $mesaj
            );

            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.facebook.com/' . $fb_id . '/notifications');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $attachment);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false); //to suppress the curl output
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            return $result;
        }
```

First function takes the app token and use it to send the notification through the second function (curl).

foreach user that has app installed and has to be notified i apply those 2 functions. 
The thing is that the second function lasts ~3 secs/user

thanks

LATER EDIT: api batch sending is the answer :) which can send max 50 notifications at a time

Comment: 19K users, “goldmine” … this smells rather spammy. Anyway, to speed things up you can use batch requests – those lower the number of HTTP requests necessary, and therefor the overall time needed to send the notifications.

Comment: no, it's not spammy at all. i notify user friends which has lower scores than him. The app actually has 240k users. ;)
Actually the batch works just fine (with a php daemon tied to it) => instant 1:1 notifications